# Missing start menu and his brothers

Tags: windows-10

I have moved the appdata folder `Local`, `LocalLow` and `Roaming` to a different location. For Roaming I just used the path option from the menu and since Local and LocalLow didn't had this option I moved them manually and set a symlink.

The Problem with Local was, that some caches didn't want to move and since I thought well a few caches can't be that bad I ingored it.

At the end it seems it wasn't only caches and neither the start menu, Systemmessage board or the clock and date menu are functional. At least the message board seems kinda working since it showing it has 3 messages but still isn't clickable.

I did this with a secondary admin account, in which all of these parts are functional any Idea how to fix this?

I already tried several times `DISM` or `sfc /scannow`without results.

Comment: Appdata is part of the USERs folder and all that should stay with the Windows drive.  To correct, make new USERs folder in the correct Windows location.

Comment: My Problem was, that appdata was growing to much, so I wasn't able to update the system. Since the second account has no problem with the start menu but missing the other appdata I am not shure if a fresh account would really help me at this point. It is no problem to setup a fresh system and I have planned this for the near future but not actually now.

Comment: @John - You can safety move the User's profile to another partition or network location.  You just have to actually move the profile. What the author did, was simply break their user profile, in a pretty significant way.

Comment: @MaKaNu - If you changes affect more than a single account the only solution is to perfect a Reset and choose the option to not keep anything that will reinstall Windows.  I have no idea how you did what you did, but you have to move the entire user profile, to do what you want.

Comment: @ramhound everything worked fine until I move local, a few file or folders had problems and I did it a bit in the rush. Since the other profile is not punished I hoped I could fix this somehow

Comment: What is actually the best practice to move the complete profile?

Comment: Best way is to make a new User profile so you can log into it. Then copy the data, email and such from the old profile to a neutral location (c:\temp). Log into the new profile and recover your data.

Comment: My last comment didn't point to how to resolve my problems. But thanks for the advice. I wanted to know what the best workflow for moving the complete profile, since most examples often just explains the Location workflow, which seems to me a bit confusing which Directory actually has the Location Tab.